# Setar "cliente" na sessão

Tags: php

Olá, provavelmente o problema possa ser mais de lógica, mas to um bom tempo em cima e não consigo solucionar.
Estou desenvolvendo um "analitycs" próprio, então quando o usuário acessa o site, recebe um "nome" fictício na sessão e é gravado nos cookies por 15min, o problema é que quando grava os logs, no primeiro acesso o sistema não envia o nome randômico gerado na sessão, apenas quando muda de página (mas já no primeiro acesso é gravado nos cookies) ou da F5, estou gravando uma cópia nos cookies. Segue abaixo o código:

```php
session_start();
if(!empty($sessaoSite) && $sessaoSite > 4){
    $SESSION['cliente'] = $sessaoSite;
}else{
    $tamanho = mt_rand(5,9);
    $all_str = "abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvxyzwABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    $nome = "";
    for ($i = 0;$i <= $tamanho;$i++){
      $nome .= $all_str[mt_rand(0,61)];
    }
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cliente'])) {
        setcookie('cliente', $nome, time() + 900);
        $SESSION['cliente'] = $_COOKIE["cliente"];
    }
}

$SESSION['cliente'] = $_COOKIE["cliente"];

$sessaoSite = $_COOKIE["cliente"];
```

Por não receber o nome no primeiro acesso, bagunça todas as informações e não consigo comparar o tempo que ficou na página, pois o primeiro acesso fica com o "cliente" em branco e não consigo agrupar essas informações.

Explicando o resto do código que não esta aqui: posteriormente eu recupero isso aqui por javascript, formato em JSON e faço um post para o arquivo que recebe as informações (data, hora, ip, navegador...) num array e envia pro servidor.
Eu colei só a primeira parte, pois acredito que o problema esteja aí, por que se eu faço um echo do $sessaoSite, também só printa depois que recupera dos cookies em outro acesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, consegui, dei uma alterada no código e declarei a variável da sessão lá no início e deu certo \o/, segue abaixo a solução, se caso mais alguém passar por isso, está aí a dica hehe

```php
session_start();
$SESSION['cliente'] = $_COOKIE["cliente"];

$sessaoSite = $SESSION['cliente'];
if(!empty($sessaoSite) && $sessaoSite > 4){
    $SESSION['cliente'] = $sessaoSite;
    $sessaoSite = $sessaoSite;

}else if($sessaoSite == null){
    $tamanho = mt_rand(5,9);
    $all_str = "abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvxyzwABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    $nome = "";
    for ($i = 0;$i <= $tamanho;$i++){
      $nome .= $all_str[mt_rand(0,61)];
    }

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cliente'])) {
        setcookie('cliente', $nome, time() + 900);
        $SESSION['cliente'] = $_COOKIE["cliente"];
        $sessaoSite = $_COOKIE["cliente"];
    }
    $sessaoSite = $nome;
}
```